# Usage of “back half”

Tags: figurative

The following article from CNBC.com states:

> Fauci says Covid could be under control in ‘back half of 2021’ if enough people are vaccinated.

I assume that by “back half” Mr. Fauci means “second half”, but I wonder if this is a common  usage, possibly an AmE one, or just a figurative, one-off,  usage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117094/discussion-between-michael-harvey-and-gio).

Answer (score 3):

It may be understood as an analogy with a train, for example. The back of the train is the part that arrives last in a station. The part of the year that arrives last is the later months leading up to December. Hence *back half of the year* is the period roughly from July to December.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that the figure of speech  is derived from more common usages of back, but is this a common usage, and is it an American English one?

Comment: Or maybe the "back nine" of a golf course, holes 10-18.

Comment: On this site (ELU Stack Exchange) a very high standard is required and it is quite common for answers to be downvoted if they are in response to low-quality questions. It has happened to me, and I have learned from it.

Comment: [Meta comment](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3198/downvoting-an-answer-because-the-question-was-bad) "It is not uncommon for users to downvote the question and all answers when they vote to close a question. This is theoretically because high rep users should know better than to answer off-topic (etc) questions. "

Comment: So you're suggesting "caboose"?

Comment: @HotLicks I like it. The caboose of the year; I hope your neologism catches on. “The caboose of the year brought up the markers of snow, frost and hail ...” (now read on)

Answer (score 1):

- It's not a one-off. 'back half' is a metaphorical way of saying 'second half'. Using 'back' instead of 'second' (of two parts) appears in other instances like the relatively common 'back nine' for holes 10 through 18 in golf.
- [It is rarer than 'second half'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=second+half%2C+back+half&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) (but note that many of those instances of 'back half' are spurious cross-sentences collocations).
- [It seems to be just as common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=back+half%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cback+half%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) in both American and British English writing